# Interrupting BlockingQueue take() in a thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, blockingqueue

I have a thread pool which creates workers and the workers take the jobs from a `BlockingQueue`.
The threads wait on `take()` from the queue.
Even on explicitly calling the thread interrupt method for the running threads, they are still waiting on `take()`. What is right way of dealing with `blockingqueue`

```
public class ThreadPoolGen {
    static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ThreadPoolGen.class);

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue;
    private int threadCount;
    private Worker[] workers;
    private Thread[] workerThreads;

    public ThreadPoolGen(int count) throws CountException{

        if(isValidCount(count))
            this.threadCount = count;
        else
            throw new CountException("Invalid Thread Count");

        workers = new Worker[count];
        workerThreads = new Thread[count];
        queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
        startThreads();
    }

    public boolean execute(Runnable task){
        return queue.offer(task);
    }

    private void startThreads(){
        synchronized (this) {

            for(int i=0;i<threadCount;i++){

                workers[i] = new Worker();
                workerThreads[i] = new Thread(workers[i]);
                workerThreads[i].start();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean shutDown(){
        try{
            for(Worker w: workers){

                w.thread.interrupt();

            }

            queue.clear();

            for(Thread workerThread : workerThreads){

                workerThread.interrupt();

            }

            return true;

        }catch(Exception e){
            LOG.debug(Thread.currentThread()+": Worker Thread Shutdown Failed");
            return false;

        }

    }

    private boolean isValidCount(int count){

        if(count<Integer.MAX_VALUE && count>0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private class Worker implements Runnable{

        final Thread thread;

        private Worker(){
            this.thread = Thread.currentThread();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                while(true){
                    try{
                        Runnable r = queue.take();
                        r.run();
                    }catch(InterruptedException interrupt){
                        LOG.debug("Interrupted exception in: "+thread.getName());
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception intr){

                this.thread.interrupt();

            }finally{

                this.thread.interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The calling class :

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("BeforeLaunch");
            ThreadPoolGen gen = new ThreadPoolGen(10);
            gen.execute(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Inside Runnable");

                }
            });

            gen.shutDown();
        } catch (CountException ce) {
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How do you know that threads are waiting on take()?

Comment: On replacing take with remove() threads exit as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're catching the exception within the `while` loop

```
while (true) {
    try {
        Runnable r = queue.take();
        r.run();
    } catch (InterruptedException interrupt) {
        LOG.debug("Interrupted exception in: " + thread.getName());
    }
}
```

Any time you interrupt this thread, it will simply loop again. Get rid of this `try-catch`. Let the outer one (outside the `while`) handle the `InterruptedException`.

Note that you might get the `interrupt` while your thread is executing `run()`, in which case an `InterruptedException` might not do what you expect it to. You should possibly set a flag so that the same thread doesn't loop again once the `Runnable#run()` is done.

Comment: Adding a volatile flag works but is it the right way to handle thread shutdown?

Comment: @arpitpanwar Shutting down a thread pool is a non trivial task. Look at the source code of `ThreadPoolExecutor` for a complex example.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a thread pool which creates workers and the workers take the jobs from a BlockingQueue. The threads wait on take() from the queue. Even on explicitly calling the thread interrupt method for the running threads, they are still waiting on take(). What is right way of dealing with `BlockingQueue`.

Seems to me that you are duplicating the behavior of an `ExecutorService`.  Is there a reason for this?  Here's the [tutorial for them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html):

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(count);
...
threadPool.submit(new Runnable() ...);
```

Sometimes there is context that needs to be held by the running threads but still it seems like your classes are overly complex.  You can still use an `ExecutorService` that share a `BlockingQueue` between the producer and the consumer threads.  You could interrupt the threads when done but you could also push `count` number of `null` objects into the queue and have your worker threads quit when they see the `null`.

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {
     // some sort of context needed to be held by each runner
     public void run() {
         while (true) {
             Work work = sharedQueue.take();
             if (work == null) {
                 return;
             }
             // do the work ...
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: ExecutorService wasnt to be used and I wanted to implement my own thread pool. I corrected the problem by putting in an object within the queue to signify that the thread must exit and also set a flag which makes the threads break of the while loop